# Symfony2 - Json Response - Generate Urls

Tags: json, symfony

What is the correct way to generate a Json Response from a Controller Action?

For example the following action is in a controller which returns Json.

```
function listAction() 
{
    ...

    $results = array();
    foreach ($orders[ 'results' ] AS $i => $row) {
        $results[ $i ] = [
            'order_name' => $row[ 'order' ]['name'],
            'shop_name' => $row[ 'order']['shop'][ 'name' ],
            'product_name' => $row[ 'product' ][ 'name' ],
            'url_shop_show' => $this->generateUrl('Shop_Show', array(
                'shop_id' => $row[ 'order' ][ 'shop' ][ 'id' ],
                'shop_slug' => $row[ 'order' ][ 'shop' ][ 'slug' ],
            )),
            'url_product_show' => $this->generateUrl('Product_Show', array(
                'product_id' => $row[ 'product' ][ 'id' ],
            )),
        ];
    }

    return new JsonResponse(
            [
                'draw' => $draw,
                'data' => $results,
                'recordsTotal' => $orders[ 'total_items' ],
                'recordsFiltered' => $orders[ 'total_items' ],
    ]);
}
```

GenerateUrl calls:

```
$this->container->get('router')->generate($route, $parameters, $referenceType)
```

The orders array is converted to a results array and urls generated.  This very much feels like presentation and therefore should be moved out of the controller.

Would it be best thing to get a template engine (Twig) to generate the output?  Or create a service for Json creation?

What is the best practice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Technically you could build a .json.twig layout but and transform the "generateUrl" method in a Twig extension.

But that requires for you to manually build your JSON in the layout and that's definitely not suggested.

Creating a JSONResponse seems a good enough solution to me.